# Why DOM changes are not visible in the function that changes DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the JS/jQuery code:

```
function swapElements(parent, i) {
     var a = parent.eq(i);
     var b = parent.eq(i + 1);

     var atemp = a.clone();
     var btemp = b.clone();

     a.replaceWith(btemp);
     b.replaceWith(atemp);

     debugOutput(); // instead of some actions
 }
 swapElements(parent, i);
```

But the `debugOutput` function sees old unchanged version DOM.

I have tried to use `MutationObserver` and `setTimeout` to call `debugOutput` but got nothing.

However if I manually check the DOM from another function:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    debugOutput();
});
```

then `debugOutput` see new changed DOM immediately.

Why this is happening? How can I work with changed DOM directly after `replaceWith` in `swapElements`?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: can you provide your `debugOutput`?

Comment: It works for me (see logs)... https://jsfiddle.net/aphe47qc/1/ Can you reproduce this problem?